# XEN GUest - Atheros WiFi driver load causes memory paging failure

Tags: memory-management, linux-device-driver, xen

Some background -

We are trying to run Qualcomm Atheros AR928X Wireless Network Adapter and have a crash right on driver load, following are our observations and questions.

The Atheros card "Qualcomm Atheros AR928X Wireless Network Adapter (PCI-Express) (rev 01)"  is plugged into the host system (datatron).
When I attach it to the DomU - the module "ath9k" is automatically loaded, but it gives an exception "iowrite32+0x2b/0x30".
No idea what the issue is (tried also with another Atheros Card (ath10k) - similar problem). When I try an Intel card, it works.
(the card also works on the Dom0 - so the Linux driver and HW is OK).

Debugging -

After some investigation with kgdb and iommu trace on DomU it seems the iomap of PCI BAR for the device returns a a mapping f which first 0x1000 bytes are read only and that causes access violation when trying to write registers mapped to this area (all the regs with offset < 0x1000) - why this happens i still don't know. Register writes with offsets > 0x1000 are fine.

Running same driver on Dom0 is totally fine

Bellow the sigsev backtrace and xen dmesg from DomU

As can be seen there is ioremap_ of size 0x10000 starting at ffffc900402c0000 but as i said, i noticed that anything bellow ffffc900402c1000 is not writable (from gdb using set addr = val) and only readable while anything above this address is writeable.

Question -

Please give any advise on this issue and especially how to approach debugging this both on Domu and Dom0 and where in xen code to look for possible issues.

```
[   37.837467] ath9k 0000:00:00.0: Xen PCI mapped GSI16 to IRQ8
[   37.837473] pcifront pci-0: read dev=0000:00:00.0 - offset 3d size 1
[   37.837498] pcifront pci-0: read got back value 1
[   37.837505] pcifront pci-0: read dev=0000:00:00.0 - offset 4 size 2
[   37.840006] pcifront pci-0: read got back value 103
[   37.853341] pcifront pci-0: read dev=0000:00:00.0 - offset c size 1
[   37.853374] pcifront pci-0: read got back value 8
[   37.853383] pcifront pci-0: write dev=0000:00:00.0 - offset d size 1 val a8
[   37.853431] pcifront pci-0: read dev=0000:00:00.0 - offset 4 size 2
[   37.853462] pcifront pci-0: read got back value 103
[   37.853472] pcifront pci-0: write dev=0000:00:00.0 - offset 4 size 2 val 107
[   37.853527] pcifront pci-0: read dev=0000:00:00.0 - offset 40 size 4
[   37.853565] pcifront pci-0: read got back value 3c25001
[   37.853574] pcifront pci-0: write dev=0000:00:00.0 - offset 40 size 4 val 3c20001
[   37.855784] mmiotrace: ioremap_*(0xf7b00000, 0x10000) = ffffc900402c0000
[   37.855842] pcifront pci-0: read dev=0000:00:00.0 - offset c size 1
[   37.855879] pcifront pci-0: read got back value 8
[   38.301919] BUG: unable to handle kernel paging request at ffffc900402c0040
[   38.301930] IP: [<ffffffff8132387b>] iowrite32+0x2b/0x30
[   38.301939] PGD 3fdf4067 PUD 3e1a8067 PMD 49d7067 PTE 80100000f7b00075
[   38.301947] Oops: 0003 [#1] SMP 
[   38.301952] Modules linked in: ath9k(OE+) ath9k_common(OE) ath9k_hw(OE) ath(OE) mac80211(E) cfg80211(E) rfkill(E) xen_pcifront(E) intel_rapl(E) x86_pkg_temp_thermal(E) coretemp(E) crct10dif_pclmul(E) crc32_pclmul(E) evdev(E) ghash_clmulni_intel(E) pcspkr(E) uio_netx(E) uio(E) autofs4(E) ext4(E) ecb(E) crc16(E) mbcache(E) jbd2(E) crc32c_generic(E) crc32c_intel(E) aesni_intel(E) xen_netfront(E) xen_blkfront(E) aes_x86_64(E) glue_helper(E) lrw(E) gf128mul(E) ablk_helper(E) cryptd(E)
[   38.302000] CPU: 0 PID: 696 Comm: systemd-udevd Tainted: G        W  OE   4.5.3-dbg #2
[   38.302008] task: ffff8800044880c0 ti: ffff8800048a8000 task.ti: ffff8800048a8000
[   38.302015] RIP: e030:[<ffffffff8132387b>]  [<ffffffff8132387b>] iowrite32+0x2b/0x30
[   38.302024] RSP: e02b:ffff8800048ab8c8  EFLAGS: 00010196
[   38.302029] RAX: 0000000000000000 RBX: 000000000000000e RCX: ffff88003ac34018
[   38.302035] RDX: ffffc900402c0040 RSI: ffffc900402c0040 RDI: 0000000000000000
[   38.302040] RBP: ffff8800048ab928 R08: 0000000000000016 R09: 0000000000000002
[   38.302046] R10: ffffffff81b08000 R11: ffffffff81b07fc0 R12: 0000000000000016
[   38.302051] R13: ffff880004b4d098 R14: ffff8800048abec0 R15: ffffffffc03c74c0
[   38.302060] FS:  00007ff256fb18c0(0000) GS:ffff88003f800000(0000) knlGS:ffff88003f800000
[   38.302068] CS:  e033 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 0000000080050033
[   38.302073] CR2: ffffc900402c0040 CR3: 0000000004a05000 CR4: 0000000000042660
[   38.302079] Stack:
[   38.302083]  ffffffffc03a70f5 0000000000000040 ffff88003ac34018 ffffffffc0339a5b
[   38.302092]  ffff88003ac34018 ffff88003ac34068 ffff88003ac81520 0000809400008090
[   38.302102]  0000000000008098 0000000000000000 0000000000000000 000000003c5869cf
[   38.302111] Call Trace:
[   38.302123]  [<ffffffffc03a70f5>] ? ath9k_iowrite32+0xde/0xf5 [ath9k]
[   38.302139]  [<ffffffffc0339a5b>] ? ath9k_hw_update_mibstats+0x62/0xd6 [ath9k_hw]
[   38.302155]  [<ffffffffc033a722>] ? ath9k_enable_mib_counters+0xc2/0x119 [ath9k_hw]
[   38.302171]  [<ffffffffc033a983>] ? ath9k_hw_ani_init+0x148/0x14b [ath9k_hw]
[   38.302182]  [<ffffffffc0313b00>] ? ath9k_hw_post_init+0x104/0x16c [ath9k_hw]
[   38.302195]  [<ffffffffc0313f22>] ? __ath9k_hw_init+0x377/0x3fd [ath9k_hw]
[   38.302206]  [<ffffffffc031403e>] ? ath9k_hw_init+0x96/0xd6 [ath9k_hw]
[   38.302218]  [<ffffffffc03a877a>] ? ath9k_init_softc+0x643/0x823 [ath9k]
[   38.302229]  [<ffffffffc03a8f7d>] ? ath9k_init_device+0x43/0x21d [ath9k]
[   38.302243]  [<ffffffffc03aad2e>] ? ath9k_tasklet+0x462/0x462 [ath9k]
[   38.302255]  [<ffffffffc03c1638>] ? ath_pci_probe+0x2c8/0x38f [ath9k]
[   38.302263]  [<ffffffff815bab16>] ? _raw_spin_unlock_irqrestore+0x16/0x20
[   38.302271]  [<ffffffff814431a4>] ? __pm_runtime_resume+0x54/0x70
[   38.302278]  [<ffffffff813566ff>] ? local_pci_probe+0x3f/0x90
[   38.302284]  [<ffffffff81357ab0>] ? pci_device_probe+0x100/0x140
[   38.302290]  [<ffffffff8143853c>] ? driver_probe_device+0x21c/0x430
[   38.302296]  [<ffffffff814387cb>] ? __driver_attach+0x7b/0x80
[   38.302301]  [<ffffffff81438750>] ? driver_probe_device+0x430/0x430
[   38.302308]  [<ffffffff81436007>] ? bus_for_each_dev+0x67/0xb0
[   38.302313]  [<ffffffff8143773f>] ? bus_add_driver+0x1df/0x270
[   38.302319]  [<ffffffffc02f0000>] ? 0xffffffffc02f0000
[   38.302324]  [<ffffffff81438fe7>] ? driver_register+0x57/0xc0
[   38.302334]  [<ffffffffc03c19ad>] ? ath_pci_init+0x23/0x25 [ath9k]
[   38.302345]  [<ffffffffc02f000d>] ? ath9k_init+0xd/0x1000 [ath9k]
[   38.302352]  [<ffffffff81002122>] ? do_one_initcall+0xb2/0x200
[   38.302358]  [<ffffffff815b74d4>] ? preempt_schedule_common+0x14/0x30
[   38.302363]  [<ffffffff815b7509>] ? _cond_resched+0x19/0x20
[   38.302371]  [<ffffffff811cf032>] ? kmem_cache_alloc_trace+0x82/0x220
[   38.302378]  [<ffffffff8116d58a>] ? do_init_module+0x5b/0x1ce
[   38.302384]  [<ffffffff810fa676>] ? load_module+0x2146/0x2790
[   38.302389]  [<ffffffff810f71d0>] ? __symbol_put+0x60/0x60
[   38.302395]  [<ffffffff810f7628>] ? copy_module_from_fd.isra.51+0xf8/0x140
[   38.302401]  [<ffffffff810faed8>] ? SYSC_finit_module+0xa8/0xd0
[   38.302408]  [<ffffffff815bb072>] ? system_call_fast_compare_end+0xc/0x67
[   38.302413] Code: 48 81 fe ff ff 03 00 48 89 f2 77 1f 48 81 fe 00 00 01 00 76 07 0f b7 d6 89 f8 ef c3 48 c7 c6 df 6a 84 81 48 89 d7 e9 85 fe ff ff <89> 3e c3 66 90 48 81 ff ff ff 03 00 77 28 48 81 ff 00 00 01 00 
[   38.302460] RIP  [<ffffffff8132387b>] iowrite32+0x2b/0x30
[   38.302466]  RSP <ffff8800048ab8c8>
[   38.302469] CR2: ffffc900402c0040
[   38.302475] ---[ end trace 092ecee276c2da16 ]---



(XEN) Xen version 4.6.0 (Debian 4.6.0-1+nmu2) (ijc@debian.org) (gcc (Debian 5.3.1-8) 5.3.1 20160205) debug=n Tue Feb  9 17:46:27 UTC 2016
(XEN) Bootloader: GRUB 2.02~beta2-36
(XEN) Command line: placeholder log_lvl=all loglvl=all guest_loglvl=all iommu=verbose
(XEN) Video information:
(XEN)  VGA is text mode 80x25, font 8x16
(XEN)  VBE/DDC methods: none; EDID transfer time: 0 seconds
(XEN)  EDID info not retrieved because no DDC retrieval method detected
(XEN) Disc information:
(XEN)  Found 3 MBR signatures
(XEN)  Found 3 EDD information structures
(XEN) Xen-e820 RAM map:
(XEN)  0000000000000000 - 0000000000099c00 (usable)
(XEN)  0000000000099c00 - 00000000000a0000 (reserved)
(XEN)  00000000000e0000 - 0000000000100000 (reserved)
(XEN)  0000000000100000 - 0000000020000000 (usable)
(XEN)  0000000020000000 - 0000000020200000 (reserved)
(XEN)  0000000020200000 - 0000000040004000 (usable)
(XEN)  0000000040004000 - 0000000040005000 (reserved)
(XEN)  0000000040005000 - 00000000d9d01000 (usable)
(XEN)  00000000d9d01000 - 00000000da191000 (reserved)
(XEN)  00000000da191000 - 00000000da192000 (ACPI data)
(XEN)  00000000da192000 - 00000000da2af000 (ACPI NVS)
(XEN)  00000000da2af000 - 00000000da6da000 (reserved)
(XEN)  00000000da6da000 - 00000000da6db000 (usable)
(XEN)  00000000da6db000 - 00000000da71e000 (ACPI NVS)
(XEN)  00000000da71e000 - 00000000daddf000 (usable)
(XEN)  00000000daddf000 - 00000000daff2000 (reserved)
(XEN)  00000000daff2000 - 00000000db000000 (usable)
(XEN)  00000000db800000 - 00000000dfa00000 (reserved)
(XEN)  00000000f8000000 - 00000000fc000000 (reserved)
(XEN)  00000000fec00000 - 00000000fec01000 (reserved)
(XEN)  00000000fed00000 - 00000000fed04000 (reserved)
(XEN)  00000000fed1c000 - 00000000fed20000 (reserved)
(XEN)  00000000fee00000 - 00000000fee01000 (reserved)
(XEN)  00000000ff000000 - 0000000100000000 (reserved)
(XEN)  0000000100000000 - 000000041e600000 (usable)
(XEN) ACPI: RSDP 000F0490, 0024 (r2 ALASKA)
(XEN) ACPI: XSDT DA2A0080, 007C (r1 ALASKA    A M I  1072009 AMI     10013)
(XEN) ACPI: FACP DA2A9C58, 00F4 (r4 ALASKA    A M I  1072009 AMI     10013)
(XEN) ACPI: DSDT DA2A0190, 9AC5 (r2 ALASKA    A M I        1 INTL 20051117)
(XEN) ACPI: FACS DA2ADF80, 0040
(XEN) ACPI: APIC DA2A9D50, 0092 (r3 ALASKA    A M I  1072009 AMI     10013)
(XEN) ACPI: FPDT DA2A9DE8, 0044 (r1 ALASKA    A M I  1072009 AMI     10013)
(XEN) ACPI: MCFG DA2A9E30, 003C (r1 ALASKA    A M I  1072009 MSFT       97)
(XEN) ACPI: HPET DA2A9E70, 0038 (r1 ALASKA    A M I  1072009 AMI.        5)
(XEN) ACPI: SSDT DA2A9EA8, 036D (r1 SataRe SataTabl     1000 INTL 20091112)
(XEN) ACPI: SSDT DA2AA218, 08A2 (r1  PmRef  Cpu0Ist     3000 INTL 20051117)
(XEN) ACPI: SSDT DA2AAAC0, 0A92 (r1  PmRef    CpuPm     3000 INTL 20051117)
(XEN) ACPI: DMAR DA2AB558, 00B8 (r1 INTEL      SNB         1 INTL        1)
(XEN) ACPI: ASF! DA2AB610, 00A5 (r32 INTEL       HCG        1 TFSM    F4240)
(XEN) ACPI: BGRT DA2AB6B8, 0038 (r0 ALASKA    A M I  1072009 AMI     10013)
(XEN) System RAM: 16263MB (16653732kB)
(XEN) No NUMA configuration found
(XEN) Faking a node at 0000000000000000-000000041e600000
(XEN) Domain heap initialised
(XEN) found SMP MP-table at 000fd7e0
(XEN) DMI 2.7 present.
(XEN) Using APIC driver default
(XEN) ACPI: PM-Timer IO Port: 0x408
(XEN) ACPI: SLEEP INFO: pm1x_cnt[1:404,1:0], pm1x_evt[1:400,1:0]
(XEN) ACPI: 32/64X FACS address mismatch in FADT - da2adf80/0000000000000000, using 32
(XEN) ACPI:             wakeup_vec[da2adf8c], vec_size[20]
(XEN) ACPI: Local APIC address 0xfee00000
(XEN) ACPI: LAPIC (acpi_id[0x01] lapic_id[0x00] enabled)
(XEN) Processor #0 7:10 APIC version 21
(XEN) ACPI: LAPIC (acpi_id[0x02] lapic_id[0x02] enabled)
(XEN) Processor #2 7:10 APIC version 21
(XEN) ACPI: LAPIC (acpi_id[0x03] lapic_id[0x04] enabled)
(XEN) Processor #4 7:10 APIC version 21
(XEN) ACPI: LAPIC (acpi_id[0x04] lapic_id[0x06] enabled)
(XEN) Processor #6 7:10 APIC version 21
(XEN) ACPI: LAPIC (acpi_id[0x05] lapic_id[0x01] enabled)
(XEN) Processor #1 7:10 APIC version 21
(XEN) ACPI: LAPIC (acpi_id[0x06] lapic_id[0x03] enabled)
(XEN) Processor #3 7:10 APIC version 21
(XEN) ACPI: LAPIC (acpi_id[0x07] lapic_id[0x05] enabled)
(XEN) Processor #5 7:10 APIC version 21
(XEN) ACPI: LAPIC (acpi_id[0x08] lapic_id[0x07] enabled)
(XEN) Processor #7 7:10 APIC version 21
(XEN) ACPI: LAPIC_NMI (acpi_id[0xff] high edge lint[0x1])
(XEN) ACPI: IOAPIC (id[0x02] address[0xfec00000] gsi_base[0])
(XEN) IOAPIC[0]: apic_id 2, version 32, address 0xfec00000, GSI 0-23
(XEN) ACPI: INT_SRC_OVR (bus 0 bus_irq 0 global_irq 2 dfl dfl)
(XEN) ACPI: INT_SRC_OVR (bus 0 bus_irq 9 global_irq 9 high level)
(XEN) ACPI: IRQ0 used by override.
(XEN) ACPI: IRQ2 used by override.
(XEN) ACPI: IRQ9 used by override.
(XEN) Enabling APIC mode:  Flat.  Using 1 I/O APICs
(XEN) ACPI: HPET id: 0x8086a701 base: 0xfed00000
(XEN) ERST table was not found
(XEN) ACPI: BGRT: invalidating v1 image at 0xce4c7018
(XEN) Using ACPI (MADT) for SMP configuration information
(XEN) SMP: Allowing 8 CPUs (0 hotplug CPUs)
(XEN) IRQ limits: 24 GSI, 1528 MSI/MSI-X
(XEN) Switched to APIC driver x2apic_cluster.
(XEN) xstate_init: using cntxt_size: 0x340 and states: 0x7
(XEN) Intel machine check reporting enabled
(XEN) Using scheduler: SMP Credit Scheduler (credit)
(XEN) Detected 2292.620 MHz processor.
(XEN) Initing memory sharing.
(XEN) alt table ffff82d0802bd010 -> ffff82d0802be240
(XEN) PCI: MCFG configuration 0: base f8000000 segment 0000 buses 00 - 3f
(XEN) PCI: MCFG area at f8000000 reserved in E820
(XEN) PCI: Using MCFG for segment 0000 bus 00-3f
(XEN) Intel VT-d iommu 0 supported page sizes: 4kB.
(XEN) Intel VT-d iommu 1 supported page sizes: 4kB.
(XEN) Intel VT-d Snoop Control not enabled.
(XEN) Intel VT-d Dom0 DMA Passthrough not enabled.
(XEN) Intel VT-d Queued Invalidation enabled.
(XEN) Intel VT-d Interrupt Remapping enabled.
(XEN) Intel VT-d Shared EPT tables not enabled.
(XEN) I/O virtualisation enabled
(XEN)  - Dom0 mode: Relaxed
(XEN) Interrupt remapping enabled
(XEN) Enabled directed EOI with ioapic_ack_old on!
(XEN) ENABLING IO-APIC IRQs
(XEN)  -> Using old ACK method
(XEN) ..TIMER: vector=0xF0 apic1=0 pin1=2 apic2=-1 pin2=-1
(XEN) TSC deadline timer enabled
(XEN) Platform timer is 14.318MHz HPET
(XEN) Allocated console ring of 64 KiB.
(XEN) mwait-idle: MWAIT substates: 0x21120
(XEN) mwait-idle: v0.4 model 0x3a
(XEN) mwait-idle: lapic_timer_reliable_states 0xffffffff
(XEN) VMX: Supported advanced features:
(XEN)  - APIC MMIO access virtualisation
(XEN)  - APIC TPR shadow
(XEN)  - Extended Page Tables (EPT)
(XEN)  - Virtual-Processor Identifiers (VPID)
(XEN)  - Virtual NMI
(XEN)  - MSR direct-access bitmap
(XEN)  - Unrestricted Guest
(XEN) HVM: ASIDs enabled.
(XEN) HVM: VMX enabled
(XEN) HVM: Hardware Assisted Paging (HAP) detected
(XEN) HVM: HAP page sizes: 4kB, 2MB
(XEN) Brought up 8 CPUs
(XEN) ACPI sleep modes: S3
(XEN) VPMU: disabled
(XEN) mcheck_poll: Machine check polling timer started.
(XEN) Dom0 has maximum 792 PIRQs
(XEN) NX (Execute Disable) protection active
(XEN) *** LOADING DOMAIN 0 ***
(XEN)  Xen  kernel: 64-bit, lsb, compat32
(XEN)  Dom0 kernel: 64-bit, PAE, lsb, paddr 0x1000000 -> 0x1d59000
(XEN) PHYSICAL MEMORY ARRANGEMENT:
(XEN)  Dom0 alloc.:   000000040e000000->0000000410000000 (4062057 pages to be allocated)
(XEN)  Init. ramdisk: 000000041d4d6000->000000041e5ff665
(XEN) VIRTUAL MEMORY ARRANGEMENT:
(XEN)  Loaded kernel: ffffffff81000000->ffffffff81d59000
(XEN)  Init. ramdisk: 0000000000000000->0000000000000000
(XEN)  Phys-Mach map: 0000008000000000->0000008001f16498
(XEN)  Start info:    ffffffff81d59000->ffffffff81d594b4
(XEN)  Page tables:   ffffffff81d5a000->ffffffff81d6d000
(XEN)  Boot stack:    ffffffff81d6d000->ffffffff81d6e000
(XEN)  TOTAL:         ffffffff80000000->ffffffff82000000
(XEN)  ENTRY ADDRESS: ffffffff81b2b1f0
(XEN) Dom0 has maximum 8 VCPUs
(XEN) Bogus DMIBAR 0xfed18001 on 0000:00:00.0
(XEN) Scrubbing Free RAM on 1 nodes using 4 CPUs
(XEN) .................................done.
(XEN) Initial low memory virq threshold set at 0x4000 pages.
(XEN) Std. Loglevel: All
(XEN) Guest Loglevel: All
(XEN) Xen is relinquishing VGA console.
(XEN) *** Serial input -> DOM0 (type 'CTRL-a' three times to switch input to Xen)
(XEN) Freed 288kB init memory.
(XEN) Bogus DMIBAR 0xfed18001 on 0000:00:00.0
(XEN) PCI add device 0000:00:00.0
(XEN) PCI add device 0000:00:01.0
(XEN) PCI add device 0000:00:02.0
(XEN) PCI add device 0000:00:14.0
(XEN) PCI add device 0000:00:16.0
(XEN) PCI add device 0000:00:16.3
(XEN) PCI add device 0000:00:19.0
(XEN) PCI add device 0000:00:1a.0
(XEN) PCI add device 0000:00:1b.0
(XEN) PCI add device 0000:00:1c.0
(XEN) PCI add device 0000:00:1c.1
(XEN) PCI add device 0000:00:1c.2
(XEN) PCI add device 0000:00:1c.4
(XEN) PCI add device 0000:00:1d.0
(XEN) PCI add device 0000:00:1f.0
(XEN) PCI add device 0000:00:1f.2
(XEN) PCI add device 0000:00:1f.3
(XEN) PCI add device 0000:01:00.0
(XEN) PCI phantom 0000:01:00.4
(XEN) PCI add device 0000:02:00.0
(XEN) PCI add device 0000:03:00.0
(XEN) PCI add device 0000:04:00.0
(XEN) PCI add device 0000:05:00.0
(XEN) PCI add device 0000:06:00.0

root@debian-guest-01:~# cat /proc/iomem 
00000000-00000fff : reserved
00001000-0009ffff : System RAM
000a0000-000fffff : reserved
  000f0000-000fffff : System ROM
00100000-3fffffff : System RAM
  01000000-015bfd4c : Kernel code
  015bfd4d-01b127ff : Kernel data
  01c65000-01d3dfff : Kernel bss
f7b00000-f7b0ffff : 0000:00:00.0
  f7b00000-f7b0ffff : ath9k
fee00000-fee00fff : Local APIC


root@debian-guest-01:~# lspci -vvvxxx
00:00.0 Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros AR928X Wireless Network Adapter (PCI-Express) (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Qualcomm Atheros AR928X Wireless Network Adapter (PCI-Express)
    Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR+ FastB2B- DisINTx-
    Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Latency: 0, Cache Line Size: 32 bytes
    Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 25
    Region 0: Memory at f7b00000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=64K]
    Capabilities: [40] Power Management version 2
        Flags: PMEClk- DSI- D1+ D2- AuxCurrent=375mA PME(D0-,D1-,D2-,D3hot-,D3cold-)
        Status: D0 NoSoftRst- PME-Enable- DSel=0 DScale=0 PME-
    Capabilities: [50] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
        Address: 00000000  Data: 0000
    Capabilities: [60] Express (v1) Legacy Endpoint, MSI 00
        DevCap: MaxPayload 128 bytes, PhantFunc 0, Latency L0s <512ns, L1 <64us
            ExtTag- AttnBtn- AttnInd- PwrInd- RBE- FLReset-
        DevCtl: Report errors: Correctable- Non-Fatal- Fatal- Unsupported-
            RlxdOrd- ExtTag- PhantFunc- AuxPwr- NoSnoop-
            MaxPayload 128 bytes, MaxReadReq 512 bytes
        DevSta: CorrErr+ UncorrErr- FatalErr- UnsuppReq- AuxPwr- TransPend-
        LnkCap: Port #0, Speed 2.5GT/s, Width x1, ASPM L1, Exit Latency L0s <512ns, L1 <64us
            ClockPM- Surprise- LLActRep- BwNot- ASPMOptComp-
        LnkCtl: ASPM Disabled; RCB 128 bytes Disabled- CommClk+
            ExtSynch- ClockPM- AutWidDis- BWInt- AutBWInt-
        LnkSta: Speed 2.5GT/s, Width x1, TrErr- Train- SlotClk+ DLActive- BWMgmt- ABWMgmt-
    Capabilities: [90] MSI-X: Enable- Count=1 Masked-
        Vector table: BAR=0 offset=00000000
        PBA: BAR=0 offset=00000000
    Capabilities: [100 v1] Advanced Error Reporting
        UESta:  DLP- SDES- TLP- FCP- CmpltTO- CmpltAbrt- UnxCmplt- RxOF- MalfTLP- ECRC- UnsupReq- ACSViol-
        UEMsk:  DLP- SDES- TLP- FCP- CmpltTO- CmpltAbrt- UnxCmplt- RxOF- MalfTLP- ECRC- UnsupReq- ACSViol-
        UESvrt: DLP+ SDES- TLP- FCP+ CmpltTO- CmpltAbrt- UnxCmplt- RxOF+ MalfTLP+ ECRC- UnsupReq- ACSViol-
        CESta:  RxErr- BadTLP- BadDLLP- Rollover- Timeout- NonFatalErr-
        CEMsk:  RxErr- BadTLP- BadDLLP- Rollover- Timeout- NonFatalErr-
        AERCap: First Error Pointer: 00, GenCap+ CGenEn- ChkCap+ ChkEn-
    Capabilities: [140 v1] Virtual Channel
        Caps:   LPEVC=0 RefClk=100ns PATEntryBits=1
        Arb:    Fixed- WRR32- WRR64- WRR128-
        Ctrl:   ArbSelect=Fixed
        Status: InProgress-
        VC0:    Caps:   PATOffset=00 MaxTimeSlots=1 RejSnoopTrans-
            Arb:    Fixed- WRR32- WRR64- WRR128- TWRR128- WRR256-
            Ctrl:   Enable+ ID=0 ArbSelect=Fixed TC/VC=01
            Status: NegoPending- InProgress-
    Capabilities: [160 v1] Device Serial Number 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00
    Kernel driver in use: ath9k
    Kernel modules: ath9k
```

Comment: I just ran into the same issue with my setup. you have gotten further than I, however.